# bash for loop to run ruby scripts

Tags: bash, ruby

I'm trying to run several ruby scripts from the command line. Here is my code so far:

```
for i in {1..59}; do $("ruby sample$i.rb"); sleep 10; done
```

The purpose is to test all these scripts quickly, but I'm getting this error:

```
ruby sample1.rb: command not found
```

I have tried all the solutions listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5236471/ruby-run-script-from-bash-script) but no luck.

What should I do to run these scripts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why complicate ?

```
 for i in {1..59}; do ruby sample$i.rb; sleep 10; done
```

when you run :  `$("ruby sample$i.rb")`

this means, run a command named "ruby sample1.rb" , then run output as command.